# Loop iteration from list

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to iterate though a list in order to get some links for the a website that has subcategories with multiple pages each. The first link in the subcategory has the first number in the list (8), the second link would have 6 and so on. My end result want to look like this:

```
sublinks: 
0   https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/
1   https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/parenting/
2   https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/pets/
3   https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/pregnancy/
```

list that try to itarate in for loop: [8, 6, 5, 13, 10, 16, 13, 15, 4, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 3, 8, 8, 1, 6, 3, 2, 15, 5, 4, 2, 12, 18, 5, 2]

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
import re


#source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])
lists =[]
lists2=[]
lists3=[]
page_links = []


for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    req = urllib.request.Request(link)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    temp1=re.findall(r'Filter by</span>(.*?)data-pagedcontenturl',str(respData))
    temp1=re.findall(r'data-totalitems=(.*?)data-pagekey',str(temp1))[0]
    pageunm=round(int(re.sub("[^0-9]","",temp1))/10)
    lists.append(pageunm)

for j in lists:
    for x in range(1, j+1):
        url_pages = link + '#pi157388622=' + str(j)
        page_links.append(url_pages)
```

My end result for the first iteration want to look like this:

```
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=1
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=2
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=3
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=4
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=5
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=6
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=7
https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/#pi157388622=8
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working currently? Your list ("list that try to iterate") has different numbers (8, 6, 5, 14...) from your desired ("want to look like") example (1, 2, 3, 4...). What do you want?

Comment: I want to make a for loop that iterates in the range on the number in the lists. for example the first would be in the range from 1-8. The second would get the second link from the subcategories and itarate from 1-6

Comment: So what is your question? Which part isn't working?  What is it doing? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: so i want my program to get the first sublink and get 8 links that will represent the 8 pages the sublink has. The second sublink would have 6 pages and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that you can't get the iteration going from 1 to the number in the initial list (outside your code sample), then you can try something like this:

```
sub_links = [8, 6, 5, 13, 10, 16, 13, 15, 4, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 3, 8, 8, 1, 6, 3, 2, 15, 5, 4, 2, 12, 18, 5, 2]
for length in sub_links:
    for number in range(1, length + 1):
        print(number, end=' ')
    print()
```

This currently prints all of the numbers you want on each line. Adjust the inner for loop body to append the number onto your link and you have what you're after.

If your question is about something else, then you'll need to be clearer - and I suggest you only include the code that is not working and explain what the problem is.